# R2dbc enum type support (mssql, oracle, mariadb, ect)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, r2dbc

With R2dbc postgresql, we can easily map java enum type with database enum type:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory pgConnectionFactory() {
        return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(
                PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .host("localhost")
                        .database("test")
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .codecRegistrar(EnumCodec.builder().withEnum("status", Status.class).build())
                        .build()
        );
}
```

Now I want to apply this mapping to: mariadb, mssql, oracle and so on.
Do these dbmss have the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB supports the same enum type as MySQL, which is just a fancy check constraint on a `VARCHAR` column, not an actual enum type.

If you want to implement database agnostic enum types across all those dialects, I recommend you use `CHECK` constraints instead of enums.

Note that hopefully, a future version of the r2dbc-postgresql driver will support enum types out of the box: https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/issues/429